# How do i "copy" a sharepoint 2010 view into a new view preserving custom formatting?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a View on a list that is customized with conditional column formatting. I want to copy this and modify it. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't say the above wouldn't be helpful to someone else, but this was what I did:

Copy out the formatting from the original view

1) open the view in Designer
2) view Source, grab and copy all the text between and including the <Xsl> tags

Paste into the new view

1) create a new view based on the original view, using the browser interface
2) open the view using the Designer
3) pasted everything from the Copy operation into the Source, between just just below the </XmlDefinition> section and above the <Data> section.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends to what purpose. What I would see as options:

1. Create a new view based on this one (same list) - should be easy via
   create new view, use this as basis
2. Export the actual view to deploy it as part of a solution. Assuming you already have the proper list definition, you would need to have either a Module, or add it as a file, considering that each view is also available in an physical .aspx file right in the same folder as your List. Via SharePoint Designer using the last node in Navigation pane you to see all files, just copy the definition of the view.

Comment: your first option doesn't work. it doesn't preserve my custom formatting done in designer (the conditional columns formatting). i will try to follow what you say in 2 but it seems very confusing.  wish me luck!